# A question my proof about the line of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I am working on Exercise 2.4.4 of Differential Geometry and Its Application.

The problem statement and my work is available at this [link](http://andrew-exercise.blogspot.com/2016/02/differential-geometry-and-its.html).

At the end of my proof, I claimed that $ S_p(\alpha') $ is both on the plane and the tangent plane, so it must be $ k \alpha' $, at this point I am unsure if that is correct. I think so because $ \alpha' $ must be on the plane and on the tangent plane, but could that two planes be the same?

Comment: Got a few upvotes, does that mean my solution is good?

Comment: In your first line, ∇u1U=−Su1(u1)=−k1u1 : is this a typo?, should be $S_p(u_1)$?

Comment: Yes, that is a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks fine.

To justify the last step, refer to [Differential Geometry and Its Applications](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xb48zk0wJfIC&pg=PA67&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false), section 2.2, which defines $T_p(M)$.

Then, $\mathtt{Lemma\; 2.2.10}$ (page 84) states that '$S_p$ is a linear transformation of $T_p(M)$ to itself'.

This is enough to justify that $S_p(\alpha ')$ lies on $P$.

And while you are on page 84, you might find $\mathtt{Example\; 2.2.12}$ useful.